# nodejs cli return [Function: values] for [].values

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I came across this today, and just want to get more on why and how `[].values` is a function

```
$ node -e 'console.log([].values)'
[Function: values]
```

Comment: @Bergi I haven't come across the array prototype before, and think of array as a map or container to store data (coming from java).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/values) is a function that your empty array inherits. It's usually called as a method and returns an iterator.